# Tooltip placement setting

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

My flex app has various Custom components. I want the tooltips for all of them to show at the top-right corner.
Is there a Application setting that I can do this with? Or do I have to do this at the component level.
Either ways, how will it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ToolTipManager.createToolTip function accepts the position (x and y coordinates) of the tooltip along with the message to display.  You'll need to calculate the position of the top-right corner of the components relative to their position within their parent component.  For example:

```
// position the tooltip to the top right of the component
var p:Point = new Point();
p.x = component.x + length;  // may want to add some padding i.e. +5 pixels
p.y = component.y;

// find coordinates in the global coordinate space
p = component.localToGlobal( p );
var tip:IToolTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip( "tooltip message", p.x, p.y );
```